# Restore wifi signal strength

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have the standard at&t uverse router with a 12/2 plan. Previously, everything worked fine with the reception as well as speed. About 18 hours ago, the reception in my room, which is separated by ONE wall from the office where the router is, practically disappeared. I power cycled router and restarted my computer. Both my phone and computer will not pick up the wifi in my room. I changed the channel, still no connection. Factory reset router, and then changed channel, still one bar. My phone shows 5 bars when right next to the router, down to 2 less than 10 feet away. How can I restore the strength of the signal?

Comment: What 802.11 mode are you using

Comment: @Ramhound 802.11b/g

Comment: Unless you have 802.11b devices your effecting the range and speed of your network by having it in that mode.

Comment: @Ramhound having the B (and 802.11-1997 DSSS) rates available actually helps range.

Answer (score 0):

Check for a loose antenna cable inside your AP.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the Wireless Access Point, and its sealed. I don't wanna void any warranties or get into trouble with my parents.

Comment: @DavidGreen If you've reset to factory defaults and tried other channels and other client devices as you've claimed, then it's most likely a hardware problem with the AP. If you don't want to check the antenna cable yourself, then [ask your parents to] call AT&T and have the unit repaired or replaced.